# Keep PHP file always running in EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a server.php file in my elastic beanstalk website that running on an ec2 instance, it creates a websocket and keep it alive with an infinite loop (takes messages and send them correct client).

But after the deployment server.php file never starts run until I open it on my browser and I am not sure if it keeps running on.

I don't know the right way to do this. If it's the correct way how can I get server.php to open after deployment and keep running always.

Comment: is PHP really a good language to do websockets? anyway can you log into the server and run `php server.php` from the command line? You might want to set up the server image to do that.

Comment: @user253751 I don't specifically about websockets, but in general PHP works well command-line, cronjob etc. - so write up your comment as an answer.

Comment: @user253751 thanks, i must do it with php. Yes, i can start it from command line but will it continue to run always?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it would have to be more detailed to be an answer and I do not know the details of how to use a custom AMI with Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: What do you mean by keep running always? you mean constantly executed? have you considered creating a cronjob on the server to execute the file every minute?

Comment: @IlanP the file has an infinite while loop, code must work on real time. So I mean file should never be closed.

Comment: Fair enough since you say it's looping infinitely,  add set_time_limit(0); to ensure execution time is unlimited and have the the file executed inside the server, keep in mind when the client drops the connection the job can be terminated so by having your server run this php file you could possibly get this to work however keep in mind your resource consumption and whether the server is set to handle a job that doesn't end.

Comment: @IlanP Thanks much, I got the point. I think the resource consumption would not be a problem even in free tier as it limited by how long it stays powered.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org). That's commonly used by [laravel](https://laravel.com) (php) to keep workers running. It's quite comfortable and has nice features that can be enabled, such as detection if a script did not successfully start, retries, automatic restarts, delayed start and some more quality of life stuff.

There appear some tutorials [link](https://kim-jangwook.medium.com/laravel-queue-work-with-supervisor-on-aws-ec2-92230a20c3c1)
and [link](https://buzzcoding.com/2018/01/08/run-scripts-continuously-on-aws-ec2-instance-using-supervisord/)